# Shuffle Password String to limit consecutive characters of same class

Tags: .net, powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

So working in IT, we have a requirement to generate secure passwords pretty much all the time, well certain organizations add more stringent requirements beyond the number of required character classes and length requirements. One such organization I work for also limits the number of characters of a single character class (lowercase, uppercase, special characters, numbers) that can appear consecutively. I have built a function that does facilitate this, however, it essentially just brute forces the password, which is pretty terrible. How would you approach this particular problem from a computer science perspective knowing speed is critical while maintaining randomness.

I feel like there should be some sort of shuffle technique I can implement, but every solution I come up with is either too slow or reduces the randomness of the string.

```
Function New-Password {
        PARAM(
            [Int]$PasswordLength            = 64,
            [Int]$MinUpperCase              = 5,
            [Int]$MinLowerCase              = 5,
            [Int]$MinSpecialCharacters      = 5,
            [Int]$MinNumbers                = 5,
            [Int]$ConsecutiveCharClass      = 0,
            [Int]$ConsecutiveCharCheckCount = 1000,
            [String]$LowerCase              = 'abcdefghiklmnoprstuvwxyz',
            [String]$UpperCase              = 'ABCDEFGHKLMNOPRSTUVWXYZ',
            [String]$Numbers                = '1234567890',
            [String]$SpecialCharacters      = '!"$%&/()=?}][{@#*+',
            [String]$PasswordProfile        = '',
        
            #Advanced Options
            [Bool]$EnhancedEntrophy = $True
        )
        
        If ([String]::IsNullOrEmpty($PasswordProfile) -eq $False) {
            #You can define custom password profiles here for easy reference later on.
            New-Variable -Force -Name:'PasswordProfiles' -Value:@{
                'iDrac' = [PSCustomObject]@{PasswordLength=20;SpecialCharacters="+&?>-}|.!(',_[`"@#)*;$]/§%=<:{@";}
            }
        
            If ($PasswordProfile -in $PasswordProfiles.Keys) {
                $PasswordProfiles[$PasswordProfile] |Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty |ForEach-Object {
                    Set-Variable -Name $_.name -Value $PasswordProfiles[$PasswordProfile].($_.name)
                }
            }
        }
        
        New-Variable -Force -Name:'PassBldr' -Value @{}
        New-Variable -Force -Name:'CharacterClass' -Value:([String]::Empty)
        ForEach ($CharacterClass in @("UpperCase","LowerCase","SpecialCharacters","Numbers")) {
            $Characters = (Get-Variable -Name:$CharacterClass -ValueOnly)
            If ($Characters.Length -gt 0) {
                $PassBldr[$CharacterClass] = [PSCustomObject]@{
                    Min        = (Get-Variable -Name:"min$CharacterClass" -ValueOnly);
                    Characters = $Characters
                    Length     = $Characters.length
                }
            }
        }
        
        #Sanity Check(s)
        $MinimumChars = $MinUpperCase + $MinLowerCase + $MinSpecialCharacters + $MinNumbers
        If ($MinimumChars -gt $PasswordLength) {
            Write-Error -Message:"Specified number of minimum characters ($MinimumChars) is greater than password length ($PasswordLength)."
            Return
        }
        
        #New-Variable -Force -Name:'Random' -Value:(New-Object -TypeName:'System.Random')
        New-Variable -Force -Name:'Randomizer' -Value:$Null
        New-Variable -Force -Name:'Random' -Value:([ScriptBlock]::Create({
            Param([Int]$Max=[Int32]::MaxValue,[Int32]$Min=1)
            if ($Min -gt $Max) {
                Write-Warning  "[$($myinvocation.ScriptLineNumber)] Min ($Min) must be less than Max ($Max)."
                return -1
            }
        
            if ($EnhancedEntrophy) {
                if ($Randomizer -eq $Null) {
                    Set-Variable -Name:'Randomizer' -Value:(New-Object -TypeName:'System.Security.Cryptography.RNGCryptoServiceProvider') -Scope:1
                }
                #initialize everything
                $Difference=$Max-$Min
                [Byte[]] $bytes = 1..4  #4 byte array for int32/uint32
        
                #generate the number
                $Randomizer.getbytes($bytes)
                $Number = [System.BitConverter]::ToUInt32(($bytes),0)
                return ([Int32]($Number % $Difference + $Min))
        
            } Else {
                if ($Randomizer -eq $Null) {
                    Set-Variable -Name:'Randomizer' -Value:(New-Object -TypeName:'System.Random') -Scope:1
                }
                return ([Int]$Randomizer.Next($Min,$Max))
            }
        }))
        
        $GetString = [ScriptBlock]::Create({
            Param([Int]$Length,[String]$Characters)
            Return ([String]$Characters[(1..$Length |ForEach-Object {& $Random $Characters.length})] -replace " ","")
        })
        
        $CreatePassword = [scriptblock]::Create({
            New-Variable -Name Password -Value ([System.Text.StringBuilder]::new()) -Force
        
            #Meet the minimum requirements for each character class
            ForEach ($CharacterClass in $PassBldr.Values) {
                If ($CharacterClass.Min -gt 0) {
                    $Null = $Password.Append([string](Invoke-Command $GetString -ArgumentList $CharacterClass.Min,$CharacterClass.Characters))
                }
            }
        
            #Now meet the minimum length requirements.
            If ([Int]($PasswordLength-$Password.length) -gt 0) {
                $Null = $Password.Append((Invoke-Command $GetString -ArgumentList ($PasswordLength-$Password.length),($PassBldr.Values.Characters -join "")))
            }
        
            return (([Char[]]$Password.ToString() | Get-Random -Count $Password.Length) -join "")
        })
        
        Switch ([Int]$ConsecutiveCharClass) {
            '0' { New-Variable -Name NewPassword -Value (& $CreatePassword) -Force }
            {$_ -gt 0} {
                New-Variable -Name CheckPass    -Value $False -Force
                New-Variable -Name CheckCount   -Value ([Int]0) -Force
                For ($I=0; $I -le $ConsecutiveCharCheckCount -and $CheckPass -eq $False; $I++) {
                    New-Variable -Name NewPassword -Value (& $CreatePassword) -Force
                    $TestPassed = 0
                    ForEach ($CharClass in $PassBldr.Values) {                   
                        IF ([Regex]::IsMatch([Regex]::Escape($NewPassword),"[$([Regex]::Escape($CharClass.Characters))]{$ConsecutiveCharClass}") -eq $False) {
                            $TestPassed++
                        }
                    }
                    if ($TestPassed -eq $CheckClasses.Count) {
                        $CheckPass = $True
                    }
                }
            }
            Default {Write-Warning -Message "This shouldn't be possible, how did you get here?!"}
        }
        
        Return $NewPassword
    }
```

Comment: "it essentially just brute forces the password, which is pretty terrible." - why is that terrible? Password generation is a _rare_ event (as opposed to, say, password _validation_), so the fact that it's computationally expensive shouldn't really be of huge concern.

Comment: for longer passwords (127 characters), it can sometimes take a couple of hundred iterations before it finds a combination that validates properly. This script is ran several thousand times a day across my networks, while the individual compute load is minimal, the collective compute load adds up over time. One such requirement is we have daily rotating passwords that need to meet specific requirements for a few resources so this script runs on each resource, every day. For servers, not an issue, for crappy thin clients, it can suck. I can't figure out any way to further optimize the script.

Comment: We can definitely help you implement a faster shuffling algorithm, but it _will_ "reduce the randomness of the string." - that's not a product of whatever approach you take, that's simply a product of the policy to not allow consecutive chars (it inherently reduces the keyspace).

Comment: O I am aware, and I have explained how limiting consecutive characters actually hurt security by reducing the possible password combinations, however, given the password length (127 characters) it is for all practical purposes a nonissue. Even with the limited consecutive chracters, when the password is that long there are too many possible combinations to brute force.

Comment: Why not build the password character by character? Remember which type was just used, and pick the next character from another a type. (The policy is not solid, it actaully decreases password entropy, but that's another a matter.)

Comment: Because that is significantly slower in the couple of ways I built it.

Answer (score 2):

> How would you approach this particular problem from a computer science perspective knowing speed is critical while maintaining randomness.

*Before moving any further, I should note that these properties (compliance with the described policy vs maintaining randomness/entropy) are mutually exclusive - you can't "maintain randomness" by carefully "correcting" the distribution of output from a PRNG.*

I would split the problem into two separate functions:

- `Test-PasswordCharSequence` - to quickly validate whether a given password string complies with the policy
- `Shuffle-PasswordCharSequence` - to randomly shuffle the characters in any given password once

Atomizing these core operations should make it easier to tune/refactor.

For the validation function, it might be tempting to use regular expression - but I would suggest simply iterating over the string and keep track of consecutive characters of the same class.

```
function Test-PasswordCharSequence {
    param(
        [string]
        $String,

        [System.Collections.IDictionary]
        $CharacterMap,

        [int]$Limit = 5
    )

    # Keep tracking the last seen character class and length of consecutive sequence
    $currentClass = ""
    $counter = 0

    foreach($char in $String.ToCharArray())
    {
        if($CharacterMap.ContainsKey($char) -and $CharacterMap[$char] -eq $currentClass)
        {
            $counter++
        }
        else
        {
            $counter = 1
            $currentClass = $CharacterMap[$char]
        }

        # if we've seen the same class for too many consecutive characters, fail
        if($counter -gt $Limit){
            return $false
        }
    }

    # No sequence over limit observed
    return $true
}
```

Then we need a function to shuffle the password. The most efficient truly random (again, depending on the RNG used) shuffling algorithm that I know of is the [in-place Fisher-Yates shuffle algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle#The_modern_algorithm), which can be implemented as follows:

```
function Shuffle-PasswordCharSequence
{
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [string]$String
    )

    $chars = $String.ToCharArray()

    $max = $chars.Length

    #Fisher-Yates Left to Right
    for($i = 0; $i -lt $max - 1; $i++)
    {
        $j = Get-Random -Minimum 0 -Maximum ($max - $i)
        $chars[$j],$chars[$i+$j] = $chars[$i+$j],$chars[$j]
    }

    return [string]::new($chars)
}
```

To use these in conjunction with your existing `New-Password` function:

```
# define character classes to use
$CharacterClasses = @{
    LowerCase = 'abcdefghiklmnoprstuvwxyz'
    UpperCase = 'ABCDEFGHKLMNOPRSTUVWXYZ'
    Numbers = '1234567890'
    SpecialCharacters = '!"$%&/()=?}][{@#*+'
}

# generate inverse character map for the validation function
# we use [Dictionary[char,string]] rather than [hashtable] to ensure case-sensitive handling of keys ('b' vs 'B')
$classMap = [System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[char,string]]::new()

foreach($entry in $CharacterClasses.GetEnumerator())
{
    foreach($char in $entry.Value.ToCharArray())
    {
        $classMap[$char] = $entry.Name
    }
}

# generate initial password
$passwordCandidate = New-Password -PasswordLength 127 @CharacterClasses

# validate generated password, shuffle until successful
$shuffleCount = 0
while(!(Test-PasswordCharSequence $passwordCandidate -CharacterMap $classMap)){
  $passwordCandidate = Shuffle-PasswordCharSequence $passwordCandidate
  $shuffleCount++
}

Write-Host "Generated valid password after ${shuffleCount} shuffles"
```

Comment: I used regex to test the characters because it was quick and worked well. I will give this shuffle sequence a try and see how it affects overall performance. Thx for the input on this.

Answer (score 0):

I think that what [@vonPryz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/503046/vonpryz) mentioned in his comment "*Why not build the password character by character?*" is actually possible and probably the fastest way to do this.
The point is that you have to create the password in 2 stages, first build a complexity list with the character**sets** (rather then the final **characters**) and than in the next stage select the concerned character for the character set on that position. If the `$MaxConsecutiveChar` is reached, choose a new character from the character set at that position:

```
Function New-Password {
    Param(
        [Int]$PasswordLength            = 64,
        [Int]$MinUpperCase              = 5,
        [Int]$MinLowerCase              = 5,
        [Int]$MinSpecialCharacters      = 5,
        [Int]$MinNumbers                = 5,
        [Int]$MaxConsecutiveChar        = 3,
        [String]$LowerCase              = 'abcdefghiklmnoprstuvwxyz',
        [String]$UpperCase              = 'ABCDEFGHKLMNOPRSTUVWXYZ',
        [String]$Numbers                = '1234567890',
        [String]$SpecialCharacters      = '!"$%&/()=?}][{@#*+'
    )

    enum CharSet {
        LowerCase
        UpperCase
        SpecialCharacters
        Numbers
    }

    $CharSets    = [system.collections.generic.dictionary[CharSet, Char[]]]::new()
    $MinSetChars = [system.collections.generic.dictionary[CharSet, Int]]::new()
    
    $MinimumChars = 0
    [CharSet].GetEnumNames().ForEach{
        $CharSets[$_] = (Get-Variable -ValueOnly -Name $_).ToCharArray()
        $MinChar = [Int](Get-Variable -ValueOnly -Name "Min$_")
        $MinSetChars[$_] = $MinChar
        $MinimumChars += $MinChar
    }

    If ($MinimumChars -gt $PasswordLength) {
        Throw "Specified number of minimum characters ($MinimumChars) is greater than password length ($PasswordLength)."
    }

    # Build a list of characters sets
    $SetList = for ($i = 0; $i -lt $PasswordLength; $i++) { $CharSets.Keys |Get-Random }
 
    # Insert the Min* required characters for the specific sets
    # Making sure that the position is not already taken by another Min* characterset
    $Used = [System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[int]]::New()
    $CharSets.Keys.ForEach{
        for ($i = 0; $i -lt $MinSetChars[$_]) {
            $At = Get-Random $PasswordLength
            if (!$Used.Contains[$At]) {
                $SetList[$At] = $_
                $Null = $Used.Add($At)
                $i++
            }
        }
    }
    
    # Elect a character for each set
    $LastChar = $Null
    $ConsecutiveChars = 1
    -Join $SetList.ForEach{
        $Char = $CharSets[$_] |Get-Random
        # Check the consecutive characters (choose another when required)
        While ($ConsecutiveChars -ge $MaxConsecutiveChar -and $Char -eq $LastChar) { $Char = $CharSets[$_] |Get-Random }
        $ConsecutiveChars = if ($Char -eq $LastChar) { $ConsecutiveChars + 1 } else { 1 }
        $LastChar = $Char
        $Char
    }
}
```

```
New-Password
X23@[X0C5%FL3Demyf5?5})f]5Kt#usC#m1+3?T(NOb4DmYsX8FA3pF46OUZeW3V
```

To prove that the `-MaxConsecutiveChar` works and is quiet fast:

```
$Params = @{
    MaxConsecutiveChar     = 1
    LowerCase              = 'ab'
    UpperCase              = 'ab'
    Numbers                = 'ab'
    SpecialCharacters      = 'ab'
}
New-Password @Params
babababababababababababababababababababababababababababababababa
```

Comment: Rereading the question, I might not have understood the "...to limit consecutive characters **of same class**". If this means e.g. an `a` should not be followed by a `b` then the answer is not correct, yet a similar "two stage" approach could be used to achieve this requirement as well and would likely be faster recreation (and checking) the whole password over and over again.

Comment: the "character" classes are lowercase, uppercase, specialcharacters, numbers. Can't have more than x number of each class consecutive. In my case its 3 characters.